# Passing a json argument to a Python subprocess from Ruby/Rails controller

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I want to use a Python script in a Rails app and I have this route defined:

```
get '/decks/:id/download', to: 'decks#download_deck', as: :download
```

Then in my view I have this link:

```
<%= link_to "Download", download_path , class: "p-2 ml-4 rounded-md bg-blue-600 text-white shadow-md align-middle" %>
```

Then in my decks#controller I have this public method:

```
  def download_deck
    @deck = Deck.find_by(params[:deck_id])
    my_hash = {}
    @deck.cards.each_with_index do |card, index|
      my_hash[index] = { "front" => card.front, "back" => card.back }
    end

    data_json = my_hash.to_json

    deck_filename = `python3 lib/assets/python/make_deck.py \""#{data_json}"\"`
    
    send_data deck_filename, filename: 'hello.txt'
  end
```

So I am making a hash with all of the information and calling to_json on it, I also have `require 'json'` at the top of the controller file. Then in the python file make_deck.py I have something like this:

```
def main():
    args = sys.argv

    data = args[1]

    print(data)

    json_data = json.loads(data)

    print(json_data)

    print('hello')
    print('world')
```

However the line `json_data = json.loads(data)` throws an error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`

What I don't understand is that I'm passing a string that is the result of calling #to_json on a hash, however then in Python json.loads() can't parse it correctly, it seems like it should. Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of escaped double quote with extra quote (`\""`) use single quote (`'`):

```
deck_filename = `python3 lib/assets/python/make_deck.py '#{data_json}'`
```